# How to send a password to `sudo` from a Dockerfile

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I am creating a docker file for local development needs. The file creates a `user` account with `user` as the password. The line that I think should work is:

```
# allow writes to the home directory
RUN echo "user" | sudo -S chmod 777 ~
```

However when I run the image interactively it seems that it failed & I see this message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/.meteor-install-tmp’: Permission 
denied
```

When I run `sudo -S chmod 777 ~` from within the container it works.

Here is the full script:

```
# docker build -t timebandit/meteor-1-5 --rm .
# docker run -v /host/path:/home/code -it timebandit/meteor-1-5 bash

FROM ubuntu:xenial

# update the system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl \
sudo \
apt-utils \
locales \
nano

# Set the locale
RUN sudo sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' 
/etc/locale.gen && \
locale-gen
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8 

# set the root password
RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd


# create a user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user
RUN adduser user sudo
RUN echo 'user:user' | chpasswd

ENV HOME=/home
WORKDIR $HOME/user

USER user
# allow writes to the home directory
ARG user_pass
RUN echo $user_pass | sudo --stdin chmod 777 /home

# install meteor
RUN echo $user_pass | sudo curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Comment: Usually in the images of docker sudo is not installed. Did you try without sudo?

Comment: @German, I installed sudo further up the Dockerfile

Answer (score 11):

I'd recommend skipping the `sudo` completely since you can change users with your Dockerfile:

```
....
# allow writes to the home directory
USER root
RUN chmod 777 /home
USER user
....
```

Adding sudo to your image means it's there for an attacker to use. You can change the user of a `docker run` or `docker exec` command with the `-u root` option any time you need to get back into the container as root.

Comment: Nice answer. And you don't need to manipulate passwords at all

Comment: It made some progress but the 'access' issue went somewhere else. Now I see `Retrying after error { [Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file] errno: 14, code: 'SQLITE_CANTOPEN' }` error. The current state of the script is thus: https://pastebin.com/RDMK546U

Comment: I wasn't able to get your Dockerfile to build, but due to a completely different meteor error. I'm not familiar with meteor, so that's best asked as a new question where others can see it.

Answer (score 3):

`~` is the user's home directory, not the `/home` directory itself.

So do the same for `/home`:

```
RUN echo "user" | sudo -S chmod 777 /home
```

Let me tell you that you have two things that are usually discouraged (password in Dockerfile and 777 perms).

And as @meatspace suggests you may use docker build args:

```
ARG user_pass
RUN echo $user_pass | sudo -S chmod 777 /home
```

And build with this:

```
docker build --build-arg user_pass=user (and the rest of the command)
```

Comment: Especially now that `build-arg` exists (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), you really have no reason to put secrets in the Dockerfile.

Comment: This seemed the more elegant solution @BMitch s solution was creating further issues although It might be more my script than his idea

Comment: Im not convinced this is working beause when the file builds that point at which the password is being passed in from the command line is appearing `red` in the build progress output

Comment: Anyone else having issues trying to pass the password into sudo using echo?  For some strange reason it just doesn't work for me.